# WPF ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility Binding problem

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, data-binding, binding

Iam using WPF with MVVM pattern.

I have a ListView and Iam trying to do a binding with the property ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility , because I need to know in the ViewModel, when the scroll of the List View is Visible to do some things later. My problem is that for any reason, when the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility is Visible (because there are some many items in the list) the property "MyScrollVisibility" is not being updated in the ViewModel.

Here is my code:

```
xaml
<ListView                                       
  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding 
  MyScrollVisibility, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >

ViewModel...
public ScrollBarVisibility MyScrollVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return _myScrollVisibility;
            }
            set
            {
                _myScrollVisibility = value;
                RaisePropertiesChanged("MyScrollVisibility");
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help or idea

Comment: This is not how it works. The property only controls the behaviour, but does not indicate the current visibility.

Comment: This attached property returns the current configuration. For the values Disabled and Visible this will work. But since this property does not reflect the layout visibility, your attempt won't work for the Auto value. You would have to find the actual ScrollBar and bind to the Visibility property. What you are doing is very unusual. The view model is not allowed to care about view (layout) related states and events. Maybe you like to explain what your true goal is? Why do you believe you need to observe the ScrollViewer in your view model class?